# How to calculate the cutoff frequency for this low pass filter?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I have to calculate the cutoff frequency for this low pass active filter.

I know the formula is:

$$ f=\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{R_1R_2C_1C_2} }$$

I don't really know if I should multiply it by 2 since there are 2 stages.

Comment: I don't know if you understood the question, I said multiply by 2 because I don't know if I should calculate the frequency for each stage and then sum them

Comment: I though you were asking about gain, my bad. But if you put two identical lowpass filters in series, will the cutoff frequency change by a factor 2? You should take both transfer functions H(f) in series: H(f)*H(f) and determine the -3 dB point of that H(f)*H(f) transfer. It is much more complex than a factor 2 since you need the -1.5 dB point of each filter.

Comment: Elena, the new cutoff frequency will be: \$\omega_{c}\:\sqrt{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}N]{2}-1}\$, where \$N\$ (in your case, that's \$N=2\$) is the number of cascaded filters and \$\omega_{c}\$ is the cutoff frequency for just one of the identical stages. You can compute all this from what @Bimpelrekkie advised. (Solving \$\bigg| H\left(j\,\omega\right)\bigg|=\bigg| \frac{-\omega_c}{j\,\omega_c+\omega_c}\bigg|^{^N}=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\$.)

Comment: The second filter is not a stable filter due to the ratio of `R7/R8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two cascaded filters, but due to the resistive dividers they are not the same. If they were, it would have been as [Bimpelrekkie](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/560039/how-to-calculate-the-cutoff-frequency-for-this-low-pass-filter#comment1460843_560039) and [jonk](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/560039/how-to-calculate-the-cutoff-frequency-for-this-low-pass-filter#comment1460910_560039) said in the comments. Either way, the frequency would be a geometric mean of the two stages. Consider two, generic, all-pole, 2nd order transfer functions:

$$\begin{align}
H_1(s)&=\dfrac{\omega_1^2}{s^2+\dfrac{\omega_1}{Q_1}s+\omega_1^2}\tag{1} \\
H_2(s)&=\dfrac{\omega_2^2}{s^2+\dfrac{\omega_2}{Q_2}s+\omega_2^2}\tag{2} \\
H_1(s)\cdot H_2(s)&=\dfrac{\omega_1^2\omega_2^2}{s^4+\Biggl(\dfrac{\omega_1}{Q_1}+\dfrac{\omega_2}{Q_2}\Biggr)s^3+\Biggl(\omega_1^2+\dfrac{\omega_1\omega_2}{Q_1Q_2}+\omega_2^2\Biggr)s^2+\omega_1\omega_2\Biggl(\dfrac{\omega_2}{Q_1}+\dfrac{\omega_1}{Q_2}\Biggr)s+\omega_1^2\omega_2^2}\tag{3} \\
\end{align}$$

To find out \$\omega\$ for a 2nd order, you would use \$(\omega^2)^{\frac12}=\sqrt{\omega^2}=|\omega|\$. Simmilarly, for an Nth order, there would be a \$\omega^N\$ term which will be calculated as \$(\omega^N)^{\frac1N}\$. In this case, it would be:

$$(\omega_1^2\omega_2^2)^{\frac14}=\omega_1^{\frac24}\omega_2^{\frac24}=\sqrt{\omega_1\omega_2}\tag{4}$$

Which is the geometric mean. Note that this would be the corner frequency as defined by the transfer function, or the frequency when the phase reaches half its final (asymptotic) value.

For your case, that particular topology is that of a [Sallen-Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology) and the transfer function for one stage is (considering the notations of the first stage):

$$\begin{align}
H(s)&=\dfrac{\dfrac{K}{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}{s^2+\Biggl(\dfrac{1}{R_1C_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2C_1}+\dfrac{1-K}{R_2C_2}\Biggr)s+\dfrac{1}{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}\tag{5} \\
K&=1+\dfrac{R_3}{R_4}\tag{6}
\end{align}$$

The two corner frequencies are the same, ~189.8 Hz, but their quality factors differ. In the picture that you're showing, the 2nd stage is not a stable filter (the phase of `V(o2)`, blue trace, goes positive), so for the overall response I modified `R7` to be `6k`, only (to get within a stable region):

[image: test]

As you can see, the corner frequency for `V(o)` is around the same place as the other two, except that the quality factor of the 2nd stage is higher and influences the overall response.